# ElasticSearch more_like_this - Are options ran on the source or destination index?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

A useful feature of the more_like_this function is ES is the ability to cross-search different indices, assuming field names and mappings correspond.

One thing that has me confused is how the Term Selection Parameters are applied in these situations.

Consider:

max_doc_freq

The maximum document frequency above which the terms will be ignored from the input document. This could be useful in order to ignore highly frequent words such as stop words. Defaults to unbounded (Integer.MAX_VALUE, which is 2^31-1 or 2147483647).

Is this the document frequency on the source document index? Or will it be applied to the index we are querying?

Example:

```
GET index_a/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "more_like_this": {
                "boost": 1,
                "fields": [
                  "text"
                ],
                "include": true,
                "like": [
                  {
                    "_id": "tI2N_24BFVRF37fDxSTT",
                    "_index": "index_b"
                  }
                ],
                "max_doc_freq": 50000,
                "max_query_terms": 50,
                "min_term_freq": 1,
                "min_word_length": 4,
                "minimum_should_match": "1%",
                "stop_words": []
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "script_score": {
        "script": "1.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

max doc freq in this case is set to 50,000. But is this on index_a? or index_b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats considered in [rewrite phrase](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/acb89dea67d7f9fd379e1330483b58873ed50f5f/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/lucene/search/MoreLikeThisQuery.java#L133) of query. so `index_b` . Rewrite phase [rewrites MLT](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/acb89dea67d7f9fd379e1330483b58873ed50f5f/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/lucene/search/MoreLikeThisQuery.java#L159) to a bool query